# Does Clojure have a 'constantly' form that executes the body function at call-time?

Tags: clojure

I want to use `constantly` in a test to model a scenario that throws an Exception. Using the off-the-shelf constantly the body is evaluated when the code is read, not executed. I.e. I can't do this:

```
(def x (constantly (throw (Exception. "X"))))
(x 1 2 3)
```

Instead, the `throw` happens immediately.

This works:

```
(defn x [&] (throw (Exception. "X")))
```

But `constantly` is so handy and idiomatic, I wonder if there's a built-in equivalent that does this, maybe using a macro?

Comment: There is a similar concept in `midje` called `unfinished`. [Look at the end.](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Top-down-testing). Incidentally, you can `(declare x)` and never define it later, but `(x)` will throw.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. My test case is handling unreliable functions rather than unfinished business. But I will take a look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative

```
#(throw (Exception. (str %&)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**constantly** is a *function* not a **macro** like `fn` so you need to use `(fn [& args])` to achieve this kind of operation.

**constantly** eagerly evaluates its parameters that's why it fails immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned this in my question. I'm asking if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't built in, but it's easy to define. Let's call it `defer`:

```
(defmacro defer [exp]
  (list 'fn ['& '_] exp))
```

Your example becomes

```
(def x (defer (throw (Exception. "X"))))
=> #'user/x

(x 1 2 3)
=> Exception X  user/x (form-init7339591407440568822.clj:10)
```

This has no practical advantage over using the [`#` reader form](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch) directly, as [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291630/1562315) does, but it is what you asked for.

---

I changed the generated function to accept arguments, as the question called for. So it is no longer a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk).

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep it in my toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to delay a computation in Clojure

The most obvious is `delay`:

```
(def x (delay (throw (ex-info "myException" {}))))
@x ;; exception is thrown
```

You could also use a lambda, similar to what would have to be done in other languages, or use laziness.

Given your code sample in the question, it looks like you are looking for something like this:

```
(defn x [& args]
  (throw (ex-info "myException" {:args args})))

(try
  (x 1 2 3)
  (catch Exception e
    (println "Exception! data is "  (ex-data e))))
```

Note the use of `ex-info` and `ex-data` which could be useful to pass information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using a future would change the contract of the function I'm mocking out, so I don't think it would work as a drop-in. Plus a delay is cached, meaning that the exception-throwing side-effect contract would also break.